# How to set a part of validation in saripaar?

Tags: android, saripaar

When I use [android-saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) I want to use only some of the validation. I used the `ViewPager` and had a dozen of `EditText`. Each page had some inputs. And I want to validate the inputs at every step.
For example, I had `username` and `password` at first step, and `phone`, `email` at the second. If user type in the invalid data at first step, validation worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer in the `ISSUE` : https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/issues/104#issuecomment-133822417

Comment: But it's not the annotation, I still want to find the simple way.

Comment: You can use a validator instance per page.